# Move body content over a certain amount, but not on the other side?

Tags: css

I want to offset the content of a div by `65px` from the left, but keep it at `100%` width. If I do this:

```
div{
margin-left:65px;
width:100%;
}
```

It will move the div over, but there will be that extra `65px` on the other side from when it was moved over. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `div`s are block elements, they expand width to fill available space automatically. Using `width: auto` will allow the left margin while letting the div fill the remaining width.

```
div {
  margin-left: 65px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks haha, I've been coding for too long today and I'm overlooking things.